# Obter a posição do um Array associativo dentro de outro Array

Tags: php, for, array-associativo

Eu tenho este array de array's associativos:

```
Array { 

    [0]=> array(4) { ["nome"]=> string(35) "ACRILEX TECIDO 37ML AMARELO CANARIO" 
                     ["preco"]=> string(4) "1.65" 
                     ["quantidade"]=> string(1) "1" 
                     ["imagem"]=> string(25) "Loja/imgPQ/4140589589.gif" } 

    [1]=> array(4) { ["nome"]=> string(35) "ACRILEX TECIDO 37ML AMARELO LIM�O" 
                     ["preco"]=> string(4) "1.65" 
                     ["quantidade"]=> string(1) "1" 
                     ["imagem"]=> string(25) "Loja/imgPQ/4140504504.gif" } }
```

E queria percorre-lo e quando encontrasse um nome igual a um dos produtos que devolvesse a posição onde se encontra esse array associativo para depois poder aceder á sua quantidade

Comment: O mais simples é através do `foreach`. Já tentou alguma coisa?

Comment: Já consegui atraves do foreach com recurso ao key => value

Comment: Respostas devem estar na área de respostas, não na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de se resolver o problema é percorrer o *array* verificando o nome de cada posição e, quando encontrar o nome desejado, retorná-lo.

```
function getKeyFromName($array, $name) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value["nome"] == $name) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Ideone](https://ideone.com/UDGHad) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/LpL9/0)</sup>

Uma alternativa é utilizar as funções [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php) e [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php) em conjunto:

```
function getKeyFromName($array, $name) {
    return array_search($name, array_column($array, "nome"));
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando em [Ideone](https://ideone.com/asCZuS) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/LpLf/0)</sup>

O resultado será exatamente o mesmo.